# How to select radio button and label with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with my radio button.
Since i styled my radio buttons, the function is not working as it should.
I've heard somewhere that i have to change something in my jquery, but i dont know what.

Can someone help me?

here is the Html code

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input"  name="state" data-order="<?php  echo $obj->order_id; ?>" value="1" type="radio" id="gridCheck1"
            <?php if($obj->status == '1'){ echo 'checked'; } else { ''; } ?> >
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Koude producten
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#gridCheck1,#gridCheck2,#gridCheck3').click(function() { 
        if(this.checked){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'change_state.php',
                data: {
                    state: $(this).attr('value'),
                    order_id: $(this).data('order'),
                    },        //--> send id of checked checkbox on other page
                success: function(data) {                           
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    //alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                     setInterval(function() {
                         location.reload();
                     }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are you using the `for=""` attribute on the labels? If you use `for="IDofradiobutton"` then your label will trigger the click on the radio button

Comment: yes like this: ```<label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheckp">
                                    Print bestelling
                                </label>```

Comment: "Can someone help me?" Unless you share some code, no.

Comment: We don't know your HTML and your function. So it will not be possible to help. Please add some sample code

Comment: I've added my Jquery you also need the code of the radio button?

Comment: @Marvin Please include your html

Comment: added the code of 1 radio button

Comment: @Marvin your code works fine when I run it, Use the `<>` and create a 1-1 example just like yours that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yeah its work fine, but it always changes the top row, even if i press the button on row 4. And when i delete some css the radio's come back. When i press them it all works like it should do. But when i press the big button i changes row 1 again.

Comment: _"but it always changes the top row"_ - The top row of what? Please share _all_ relevant code. In your success callback you're always updating the same (for us unknown) element that has the id `container`. It's really hard to know what the actual issue is here since the question is pretty vague. Please edit the question to include a proper and detailed explanation of what should happen and what currently happens.